# You're trying to create an attribute in Rails 3.2.5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a DI routine where I have a large csv I'm importing with known column format.  I first set up a column map:

```
col_map =
    {
      4 => :name,
      6 => :description,
      21 => :in_stock,
      ...
```

I then read each line in, and then using the column map, attempt to set the attribute:

```
i = Item.new
col_map.each do |k,v|
    i[v] = chunks[k] #chunks is the line read in split by the delimiter
```

In my item declaration, I declare two attributes, b/c these are not stored in the database, they're used for other logic:

```
attr_writer :in_stock
attr_writer :end_date
```

When the code gets to this line:

```
i[v] = chunks[k]
```

I get this message:

```
X.DEPRECATION WARNING: You're trying to create an attribute `in_stock'. Writing arbitrary attributes on a model is deprecated. Please just use `attr_writer`
```

But I'm not trying to create an attribute, and I am using attr_writer.  I suspect this has something to do with the [] I'm using instead of . for the lvalue.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks for any help,
Kevin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Admittedly, the deprecation wording is slightly confusing, but you're seeing this warning because the `model[attribute_name] = ...` style is only supported for ActiveRecord attributes on the model, not non-persisted attributes added with `attr_writer`.

You can see the code that produces the warning [over here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/d94d77c55c59f861201ac42f991ede0ff31481d5/activerecord/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/write.rb#L31).

To address this I'd use `send` which will work for all attributes e.g.

```
i.send("#{v}=", chunks[k])
```

Comment: awesome thank you, that's exactly the gap in my knowledge i was seeking.